# Unable to Connect IBM MQ Via ASP.NET - Unable to load DLL 'amqxcs2.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to check the connection with one of active IBM MQ’s but I am getting this error..
Unable to load DLL 'amqxcs2.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
I am using the following code..
Included   amqmdnet.dll and amqmdxcs.dll in bin and gave the same reference to the project.

using IBM.WMQ;
using IBM.WMQ.PCF;

Any remedy for this.
Thanks
Sreenath

Comment: I am using Windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the file is not present, make sure the library is either where the application needs it to be or the library is in the GAC.

If the file is present and the error still occurs, make sure the file is not blocked. Open the file properties and check if there is a button "unblock" in the "General" tab of the properties window. If so, klick it and try again. This seems to happen when you download a library or extract a library from an archive downloaded from an untrusted source.

Comment: Do I need to have MQ Series client installed in my Computer for this..?

Comment: i don't think so. Your application just seems to be unable to find the dll at runtime.

Comment: I have these dlls in my Bin for sure.

Comment: did you check for the "unblock"-Button in the properties of these DLLs? If that's not it, it could be that another library referenced by amqxcs2.dll is missing and the load fails because of that unmentioned reference. I did a short google search and on mqseries.net i found a rather old thread from 2004 dealing with the same problem. Maybe the solution provided there will help you. In essence they talk about adding the whole installation directory to the ASP.Net search path/copying all dlls from the install directory into the system32 directory.

Comment: Link to the thread: http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=55359&sid=fdc2b2981998f86680c6352d7dcb9d63

Comment: @GarlandGreene Unblocking is a good tip, but these dlls are not .NET assemblies and therefore cannot be place in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a COM error. The IBM assembly is probably a native dll and so you cannot register it in the GAC, which is for .NET dlls only. Native COM dlls can be registered with [Regsvr32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx). This error can also occur if a native dll has a dependency on another dll that is missing. Also see [Understanding Dependencies of a Visual C++ Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235265.aspx) which gives information about the Dependency Walker tool that can be used to figure out the depndencies for a native dll.